# Bad bind varible error - Oracle Forms

Tags: forms, oracle, plsql

I have a oracle forms canvas which contains three tabs and I want to add two tabs too. So I created 2 new blocks manually. When I debugged this code I am getting this error:

> **"bad varible 'BL_Aptima.Cevap765' "**

and I can't change tabs' name.

I guess, I didn't create blocks correctly. How can I identify it correctly?

```
 PROCEDURE DOKTOR_DOLDUR (CV_SITOLOJI_TIP VARCHAR2)IS
 BEGIN
 IF CV_SITOLOJI_TIP IS NULL THEN
  NULL;
                  ....
 ELSIF CV_SITOLOJI_TIP = 'Z' THEN
  IF :BL_APTIMA.CEVAP4337 IS NOT NULL THEN
         :BL_APTIMA.CEVAP4337_DESC :=   Func_Gnl_Personel_Bilgi_Getir(:BL_APTIMA.CEVAP4337 , 'AD_SOYAD');
  END IF;
  IF :BL_APTIMA.CEVAP739 IS NOT NULL THEN
         :BL_APTIMA.CEVAP739_DESC := Func_Gnl_Personel_Bilgi_Getir(:BL_APTIMA.CEVAP739 , 'AD_SOYAD');

  END IF;
  IF :BL_APTIMA.CEVAP740 IS NOT NULL THEN
     :BL_APTIMA.CEVAP740_DESC := Func_Gnl_Personel_Bilgi_Getir(:BL_APTIMA.CEVAP740 , 'AD_SOYAD');
  END IF;
            ....
```

Comment: I can't see the images. Is that the name of one of the fields of your new block?

Comment: @pablomatico Yes, my new block is " BL_Aptima "  and  I am getting error about this block.

Comment: @xsentius are you sure that the CEVAP765 item was created?

Comment: @pablomatico I have a   tab called " smear " and i want to create same content but different tab called  " aptima ", so I created manully (not use data block wizard) new data block, BL_aptima,used same item for it.I guess, couldn't create data block correctly ? because it isnt recognise BL_aptima

Comment: the error is telling you that you need to create an item named cevap765 inside your new block

Comment: @pablomatico I solve this problem, thank you; but now i didn' t see my label in the form and didn' t change my tabs' name when i debugged it.

Comment: what label @xsentius?

Comment: @pablomatico It meand display items' contens

Comment: sorry I don't understand, what's exactly your problem? could you please elaborate on that a little bit?

Comment: I give a name each display item like " soru765" and when i debugged this forms i didnt see content of this items. It came like blank

Comment: Are you sure you assigned values to those display items?

Comment: @pablomatico Yes, I am getting values from database.

Comment: How are you getting those values? Make sure the code is getting called and that is working ok.